# in ObjectBox, using ToMany vs using my own list of string ids in managing relations?

Tags: objectbox

Take the example from the documentation, using ToMany relations:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id public long id;
    
    // 'to' is optional if only one relation matches.
    @Backlink(to = "customer")
    public ToMany<Order> orders;
    
}

@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id public long id;
    
    String stringId;
    ...
}
```

where stringId in order is a long string like "CS-DE-AA-order1234567890".

For the same purpose, if I keep a list of string ids and manage them myself, it would be like:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id public long id;
    
    String orderIds;
}
```

where orderIds keeps Orders' stringId separated by space, like:
"CS-DE-AA-order1234567891 CD-DF-AB-order1234567891 CT-SE-BB-order1234567892 ..."

So I would like to know how the two schemes compare in terms of performance, efficiency and disk storage.

Answer (score 1):

Native relations have several advantages:

- For 1:N relations, the ID is embedded in the object on the N side (pointing to a single object) consuming 8 bytes
- Relations use the object ID, which can be looked up faster than any query
- Relation properties are automatically indexed for efficient access
- In queries relations allow you to link between types (aka "join")
- Scalable; even if you had millions of relations, removing/changing/adding one relation would be very efficient

You can still ignore those advantages and be happy with what you are doing, as it might be good enough for your use case. You know, you did not include specifics and it all depends...

Comment: I implemented ToMany relations on both side across two of my models.  Excellent.  The app appears more performant.  The code is more elegant.  But there appear some downsides.  One relates to large memory consumption mainly at time of bulk import of data.  I have to shrink my bulk size, resulting in more DB reads/writes.  And, as relations grow along the import process, I need to adjust the bulk size dynamically to avoid running out of memory.

Comment: Another downside relates to disk storage.  Previously, I had a list of string ids in one of my model referencing the other model.  So it's a one-sided relation.  The DB file size in my test case is about 600MB.  The ids are 22-letter long strings (12 being digits).  After I implemented the ToMany relations (now two-sided relations though) and got rid of the list of string ids (I still keep the ids in models), the DB size grows to over 700MB (a 15% increase).

Comment: I am not positive if the 15% growth is purely due to the ToMany relations because I don't know if the list of ids are actually removed from the DB file.  I just removed the field from the model without first setting it to null.  I asked a question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66398490/objectbox-deleting-a-field-in-model, to which an ObjectBox personnel replied no, and I am looking for more confirmation.