# ObjectBox: deleting a field in model

Tags: objectbox

When I delete a field in a model, I can see from the db browser that the field is deleted, but I don't quite see the size of the DB file change.  How and when is the deletion reflected in the DB file?

Answer (score 1):

The field/property is marked as retired (observe the UID of the property being moved to the retired section in the model file `default.json`), no data is actually removed. If that is a concern, write code to update all objects (e.g. set that field to null, then put) before removing the field/property.

You might also be interested in [the reclaim disk space question](https://docs.objectbox.io/faq#how-does-objectbox-use-disk-space-and-can-i-reclaim-disk-space).

Comment: Thanks.  I do find a bunch of properties in the retired section.  They have been removed from the models in the past.  I had not set them to null before removing them from the models.  Actually, in the json file, there are now retiredEntityUids, retiredIndexUids, and retiredPropertyUids, all containing many UID's, which I don't what they have been.  So is there a way to reclaim the disk space taken by these removed stuff without removing the entire DB files?

Comment: I tried to put a couple of my recently deleted fields back into the models and the app shows null on the fields.  What does that mean?  Then, I tested by importing parts of my data into a new installation of the app and checked the size of the new DB file, so by estimate, it seems the size of the old DB file is in line with the new DB.  So perhaps the data in my deleted fields had been removed from the old DB?  Can you please explain?

Comment: I tried putting back the removed field with its uid tag: @Uid(4761584476660048242L). but When I compiled, it says "no property with UID 4761584476660048242 found".  In the json file, this uid is actually in the retiredPropertyUids section.

Comment: You need to also revert to the original default.json model file.